# Two circles with a common external tangent problem.

Tags: geometry

Two circles are tangent externally at A, and a common external tangent touches them at B and C. The line segment BA is extended, meeting the second circle at D. Prove that CD is a diameter.

Comment: Welcome, what did you try? Did you sketch a picture, did you add some extra lines or points?

Comment: Hi, i sketched like 20 drawings, all the same thankfully, because i wasn't lost at all, but I spent the whole afternoon thinking about this, and i couldn't arrive at the conclusion, I tried assuming it was true and work backwards but couldn't find a true statement. But well, i am not very good at geometry so that is why i am practicing, and well i wanted to know about how to prove this, because it may yield a step that i was missing in my current knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the point where $BC$ and the common tangent through $A$ intersect.  $|AE|=|BE|$ for the two tangent segments from $E$ to the circle containing $A$ and $B$, thus triangle $AEB$ is isosceles with $\angle BAE =  \angle EBA$.  Likewise  $\angle CAE =  \angle ECA$.

Then

$\angle BAC = \angle BAE +  \angle CAE = \angle EBA +  \angle ECA = \angle CBA +  \angle BCA$.

But also

$\angle BAC + \angle CBA +  \angle BCA = 180°$ in triangle $ABC$.

Then $\angle BAC = 90°$, and the inscribed $\angle CAD$ which is supplementary to $\angle BAC$ is also $90°$.  This identifies the chord $CD$ as a diameter.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i couldnt solve it because i forgot the property that two tangen lines of a circle intersect yielding an isosceles triangle.